# Sharepoint webpart upload file whitout using "runat server"

Tags: sharepoint, file, upload, web-parts

For uploading a file in sharepoint I use a webpart and an automatically generated form.

the tag for the upload file:

```
<input type="file" id="uploadfile" name="uploadfile" />
```

When I try to pick it up after posting, the file isn't accessible with the Request.Files attribute (Request.Files["uploadfile"]). (Request.Files looks like null on sharepoint)

Is there a solution in sharepoint without using the "runat=server" on the input tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To upload files to sharepoint you need to set enctype (enctype="multipart/form-data") on the form tag. Sharepoint doesn't add it when you use .

When using non ASP.NET controls, you can use 'this.Page.Form.Enctype = "multipart/form-data";' On Page_Load to add the enctype.

Answer (score -1):

Is there a reason why you can't just use the ASP.NET [FileUpload](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/standard/fileupload.aspx) control? This will do all the hard work for you.

You can access a stream for the file via the [FileContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filecontent.aspx) property or as an array of bytes via the [FileBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filebytes.aspx) property. Its filename is available via the [FileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filename.aspx) property.

Comment: I'm using a self-made lightweighted framework, and try to avoid as much as possible the ASP.NET controls. But if there's no work around, I will use the basis ASP.NET FileUpload.

Comment: That's an admirable goal. There may be a way, but SP inserts some pretty low-level stuff as you can see from web.config. This is probably what's causing the problem but an expert in ASP.NET and SharePoint may know for sure.